# runnable.run() cannot throw exceptions

Tags: java, exception, runnable

I am using `ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskA....)` to do some task.

I want the whole process to fail when taskA throws an unhanded exception. However, `taskA` has to be `runnable` and its method, `run()`'s signature doesn't throw any checked exceptions.

Does anybody know how to make this?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is to use the `Callable` interface, available since Java 5.0

`Callable` works just like `Runnable`, but it allows you to return a value, as well as to throw an `Exception` from the child thread.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html